# The origin of the word "Pink"

Tags: etymology

I do not know how else to put the question.  On my third attempt, what is the origin of the word "pink" in the English language?

Comment: Try [this](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pink&searchmode=none).

Comment: The latin 'rosea' does not solve the derivation of the word "pink" therefore, it is of interest to know the origin and whether it is contained in another language

Comment: Did you look at Brian's link???

Comment: Your answer is here: - http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pink&searchmode=none

Comment: Why have you written "on my third attempt"? And "I do not how else to put the question"?

Comment: Ahh... did the site prevent you from posting the question because you didn't meet the minimum character limit? One very easy way to overcome this obstacle is to copy and paste a definition from a dictionary or a Wikipedia article. This also shows the community you have at least attempted some minimal research. Another option is to explain "why" you are interested in knowing the word's origin. Is it only curiosity, is there a wager between you and another person, are you doing some research and you have come to a standstill? In the end, it's not really that hard to meet the character limit.

Comment: @Angela: Please try searching for it yourself first. It took me 30 seconds to find the answer on Google by just entering "origin of word pink."

Comment: @MishaRosnach Really? What's the answer?

Comment: @Araucaria: Here is the link to the google search *origin of word pink.*  Please feel free to click on the first link, second link, third link, or the Google answer. https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=origin%20of%20word%20pink&oq=origin%20of%20word%20pink&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.2535j0j7

Answer (score 4):

I have read (can't remember where) that the colour **pink** comes from the name of the flower. And the flower was so named because its edges are **pinked**; i.e shaped as they would be if cut with **pinking shears**; **To pink** meaning to give a decorative frilly edge.

**Edit: a reference -**

> The color pink is named after the flowers called pinks... The name
>   derives from the frilled edge of the flowers—the verb "to pink" dates
>   from the 14th century and means "to decorate with a perforated or
>   punched pattern" (possibly from German pinken, "to peck").[6] While
>   the word "pink" was first used as a noun to refer to a color in the
>   17th century, the verb "pink" continues to be reflected today in the
>   name of those hand-held scissors that cut a zig-zagged line referred
>   to as pinking shears. -[*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink)

Answer (score 4):

It looks as if the only certain etymology is for hunting **[Pink,](http://www.thomaspink.com/AboutUs/content/fcp-content)** the scarlet coats worn when riding to hounds. They are named after the inventor, like Burberrys and Macintoshes. The Tailors who designed the coat still have a shop in London.

The subject is complicated. Even the Shorter Oxford English Dictionary has a column of Pinks, with ten separate headings. Shorter OED :: 'Pink' is my source.

**1471** Pink refers to a fishing boat.
**1490** to a minnow and by 1500 to salmon smaller than smolts. Are they pink?
**1512** it means an eyelet, and a century later a stab wound. That might be pink.
**1573** it begins to be used to describe a number of flowers (esp. Dianthus)

**1634** is the earliest recorded use of pink to mean a pigment. The pinks are all **lakes,** that is they are all made by staining precipitated chalk or ground cuttle-fish bone. The actual Paint is made from pigment mixed with a medium (oil, gum, wax, egg)

> 1634 [origin obscure] A yellowish or greenish-yellow pigment or 'lake'
>   obtained by the combination of a vegetable colouring matter with a
>   white base etcetera...

At some time other pinks were created. By 1819 it was possible to buy four pink pigments. I do not know if this includes the "yellowish or greenish-yellow." This is all from *Rees Cyclopedia*.

> **Brown Pink**  ...of a yellow or orange colour ...take French berries,
>   one pound; of fustic wood in chips, half a pound; and of pearl ashes,
>   one pound, Boil an hour .... add a solution of alum.
>
> **Dutch Pink**  one pound of French berries, and four ounces of turmeric
>   root... **English Pink** is a pale form of Dutch Pink.
>
> **Rose Pink** is a lake, ...principally chalk, the tinging (sic) substance
>   is extracted from Brasil or Campeachy Wood (1lb of each to 2 gallons
>   of water).  "The goodness of rose pink consists chiefly in the
>   brightness of the colour and the fineness of the substance."

Comment: So far as I can tell, until mid 1700s pink was called 'Rose.' Shakespeare's Pink means 'Tip-top,' --the pink of health.

Answer (score 2):

**[Etymology of word pink, from Google:](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=pink%20etymology)**

> mid 17th century: the early use of the adjective being to describe the color of the flowers of [this plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dianthus).
>
> Origin: mid 17th cent.: adjective describing the color of the flowers of pink |pɪŋk| (flower name) -- a herbaceous Eurasian plant with sweet-smelling pink or white flowers and slender, typically gray-green, leaves. • Genus Dianthus, family Caryophyllaceae (the pink family). This family includes the campions, chickweeds, stitchworts, and the cultivated carnations...

Comment: _pink_  |pɪŋk| (color name) Origin: mid 17th cent.: adjective describing the color of the flowers of _pink_ |pɪŋk| (flower name) -- a herbaceous Eurasian plant with sweet-smelling pink or white flowers and slender, typically gray-green, leaves. • Genus _Dianthus_, family _Caryophyllaceae_ (the pink family). This family includes the campions, chickweeds, stitchworts, and the cultivated carnations.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, "etymology obscure" according to the *OED*.  Sometimes the answers to simple questions about word origin have been lost.

Answer (score 1):

Etymonline has [an entry on pink](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pink&allowed_in_frame=0). It says that "pink" was the common name of a garden plant. The origin of the word pink itself is unknown. The rest of the text consists of assumptions.